# How to test subscription inside method

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, jasmine-marbles

Consider this angular component:

```js
export class CheckoutComponent {
  constructor(private paymentService: PaymentService, private paymentModalService: PaymentModalService) {}

  public onCheckout(): void {
    const paymentStatus$: Observable<string> = this.paymentService.getStatus();

    const paymentRequired$ = paymentStatus$.pipe(map(paymentStatus => paymentStatus === 'INCOMPLETE'));

    paymentRequired$.subscribe(() => {
      this.paymentModalService.open();
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a jasmine test to confirm that `paymentModalService.open()` was called:

```js
import { cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';

describe('CheckoutComponent', () => {
  let component: CheckoutComponent;
  let mockPaymentService: jasmine.SpyObj<PaymentService>;
  let mockPaymentModalService: jasmine.SpyObj<PaymentModalService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockPaymentService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getStatus']);
    mockPaymentModalService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['open']);
    component = new CheckoutComponent(mockPaymentService, mockPaymentModalService);
  });

  it('should open payment modal if required', () => {
    mockPaymentService.getStatus.and.returnValue(cold('a', { a: 'INCOMPLETE' }));
    component.onCheckout();

    expect(mockPaymentModalService.open).toHaveBeenCalled(); // FAIL: was never called
  });
});
```

However the open method was apparently never called.

Is there any way to wait for the cold test observable to complete emit before asserting that the method has been called?

I've tried using `fakeAsync` and `tick` but it does not either seem to help. I realize it works with `of()` instead of a `TestColdObservable`, but I would like more granular control of observable behavior. I don't really intend to complete the `getStatus()` observable.

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `mockPaymentService.getStatus` and putting the expect in the callback?

Comment: Not sure how, compiler complains about subscribe not existing as a property of `mockPaymentService.getStatus`

Comment: Oh rather than a spyObj you can inject the service via `mockPaymentService = TestBed.inject(PaymentService);`

Comment: If you put a `console.log` inside of the subscribe, do you see it? I am thinking it should be `cold('a|',...` where `|` is the complete signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading documentation on [component marble tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-marble-tests) I found that I need to flush the test scheduler like so:

```
import { cold, getTestScheduler } from 'jasmine-marbles';

it('should open payment modal if required', () => {
  mockPaymentService.getStatus.and.returnValue(cold('a', { a: 'INCOMPLETE' }));
  component.onCheckout();
  getTestScheduler().flush(); // <=== prompt the scheduler to execute all of its queued actions

  expect(mockPaymentModalService.open).toHaveBeenCalled(); // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer as the solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest you something, which is not really to the point of your question but can help anyways.

My suggestion is to move logic from the component to the service.

Looking at your code it seems that the `CheckoutComponent` needs an observable, `paymentRequired$`, which notifies when a payment is required.

Let's assume `this.paymentService.getStatus()` is a call to a back end API, which returns the status of payments. In this case, what I would do in the service would be something like this

```
export class PaymentService {
  constructor(http, ...)

  // Private Subjects - using Subject to notify allows multicasting
  private _paymentRequired$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  // Public API Streams
  public paymentRequired$ = this._paymentRequired$.asObservable();

  // Public API methods
  public getStatus() {
    this.http.get(....).pipe(
      tap({
        next: resp => this._paymentRequired$.next(resp === 'INCOMPLETE'),
        error: err => {// manage the error case}
      })
    )
  }
}
```

If you move the logic to the service like this, then the `CheckoutComponent` can simply subscribe to the `paymentService.paymentRequired$` observable in its `ngOnInit` method, and the the test can deal only with service and not the component.

In particular the test would have to instanciate somehow the service, subscribe to the `paymentRequired$` observable, invoke `getStatus()` and check if `paymentRequired$` has notified.

Answer (score 0):

Your main question is:

> I would like more granular control of observable behavior. I don't really intend to complete the getStatus() observable.

If you do not want to complete it then it essentially is not a cold observable, its a hot observable, that would mean you can create a subject and pass

```
   var sub = new Subject();
    mockPaymentService.getStatus.and.returnValue(sub.asObservable());
    // run method and let it subscribe 
    component.onCheckout();
    
// fire it
    sub.next('a', { a: 'INCOMPLETE' });
 expect(mockPaymentModalService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I would suggest you go through the document of how to write component test-cases:
[Angular guide to writing test cases](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency)

Problem:
In your current method of testing you won't be able to run component life-cyle, and instead would be running them manually and skip on real-life test cases.
It is fine for service but not components.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the solution in the linked documentation on [component marble tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-marble-tests). Documentation states that "in many cases, testing the component class alone, without DOM involvement, can validate much of the component's behavior in an easier, more obvious way."